# Why onclick Javascript not working for multiple dropDowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I currently have 2 drop down boxes that are the same classes and whatnot, the data is being populated with information from MySQL.

```
<section id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" onclick="firstDropDown()">
    <span class="anchor">Boards</span>
    <ul class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="'.$boardiD.'">'.$boardName.'</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I have two of the above, when displayed on the page, only the first drop down menu opens when I click on it.

The following is the JavaScript that is currently being used, that I adjusted from another but neither of them allow all the checkboxes to be opened.

```
function firstDropDown()
{
    var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');

    checkList.onclick = function (evt)
    {
    if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
        checkList.classList.remove('visible');
    else
        checkList.classList.add('visible');
    }   
}
```

The original code is this one... but it was having problems when I included two list1 drop downs.

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');

checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt)
{
if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
    checkList.classList.remove('visible');
else
    checkList.classList.add('visible');
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle of the problem: I tried including a specific id in the anchor and include in the javascript but not even that worked: http://jsfiddle.net/3GY74/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they both have the same id? You need to make sure the ids are unique and that your function takes into account the correct element:

I recomend that you change:

```
<section id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" onclick="firstDropDown()">
```

to:

```
<section id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" onclick="firstDropDown(this)">
```

And then change this:

```
function firstDropDown()
{
    var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
```

To:

```
function firstDropDown(checkList)
{
```

This will allow "checkList" variable to be dependent on the element that was activated.

Answer (score 1):

IDs are supposed to be unique! Make sure both lists have different IDs. Also, you may want to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` in case you want multiple events attached to the lists, as `.onclick` only supports 1.